# Twilio PHP: How to authenticate a Connect app?

Tags: php, twilio

I'm getting this error:

> [HTTP 404] Unable to fetch record: The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts/AC********************.json was not found

When I try to create a Twilio Client like this:

```php
new \Twilio\Rest\Client(env('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'), env('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'), $customerAccountSid)
```

`TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID` and `TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN` are from an API key I created at https://www.twilio.com/console/project/api-keys I chose "Main" key type because the other gave an even worse error.

And then `$customerAccountSid` is an "AC" account ID that Twilio sent back to my app when I click on a "Connect" button that links to `https://www.twilio.com/authorize/CN********` where that "CN" ID is my Connect SID, and the "AC" account is a 2nd account I set up for testing.

Why can't the Twilio client fetch the account? It should be authorized to connect now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think this is similar to [our other discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68614430/twilio-list-phone-numbers-for-connected-app), but for more information, Connect apps pre-date API Keys and are intended to work with Account SIDs and Auth Tokens.

So, to fix this you will need to use your account's auth token and the connect account's SID to make requests.

```php
new \Twilio\Rest\Client($customerAccountSid, env('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'), $customerAccountSid)
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought I could simplify the problem by taking PHP out of the picture. So yeah, pretty much the same problem. The first arg is the customer SID that the Connect button sends back, and the 3rd arg I'll have to obtain from the accounts API to look up their main account.

Comment: Appreciate trying to simplify the problem. I'm just going through the tag backwards and got to this question second. Glad you're unblocked on this now.

Comment: Actually.. it's weirder than that. To actually send an SMS you're supposed to use `($yourAccountSid, $yourAuthToken, $theirAccountSid)`. To list their accounts, you use `($theirConnectedId, $yourAuthToken)`. To list their phone numbers, you use `($theirConnectedSid, $yourAuthToken, $theirAccountSid)`