# Twilio: List phone numbers for connected app

Tags: api, curl, twilio

If I run this:

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/'$TWILIO_CONNECTED_APP_SID'/AuthorizedConnectApps/CN***.json' -u "$TWILIO_CONNECTED_APP_SID:$TWILIO_CONNECTED_AUTH_TOKEN" -sS | jq
```

I can see that my app is authorized:

```json
{
  "connect_app_sid": "CN***",
  "account_sid": "AC***1",
  "permissions": [
    "get-all",
    "post-all"
  ],
  "connect_app_friendly_name": "*** Dev Connect App",
  "connect_app_description": "*** test account",
  "connect_app_company_name": "***",
  "connect_app_homepage_url": "https://***.com/",
  "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC***/AuthorizedConnectApps/CN***.json"
}
```

But when I try to list all the phone numbers for that account using my app credentials:

```sh
curl -X GET 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/'$TWILIO_CONNECTED_APP_SID'/IncomingPhoneNumbers.json' -u "$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN" -sS | jq
```

I get:

```
{
  "code": 20003,
  "detail": "",
  "message": "Authenticate",
  "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20003",
  "status": 401
}
```

I can't figure out why. I know those credentials work because I can list my subaccounts:

```sh
curl -X GET 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts.json?Status=active' -u $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN -sS | jq
```

I just can't seem to get any info for my connected accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you make a request on behalf of an account that is connected through Twilio Connect you should [authenticate the request with the connected account's SID but your auth token](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/connect/quickstart/ruby#making-an-authorized-request). The account's SID also goes into the URL for API requests under the `2010-04-01`  namespace.

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/'$TWILIO_CONNECTED_APP_SID'/IncomingPhoneNumbers.json' \
 -u "$TWILIO_CONNECTED_APP_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN" -sS | jq
```

Comment: Hmm, that succeeds but what is this "Subaccount for ConnectApp" that it's trying to use? That one doesn't have any phone #s attached to it and it's not even listed in the console: https://www.twilio.com/console/project/subaccounts It does show when I do `curl -X GET 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts.json' -u "$TWILIO_CONNECTED_APP_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN" -sS | jq` though -- how do I connect using the main account instead?

Comment: I think this is down to the permissions model of Connect. Check out [the paragraphs under "Permissions" here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/connect#permissions).

Comment: Oh.. I think I figured it out just now. You have to do `curl -X GET 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/'$TWILIO_CONNECTED_MAIN_ACCOUNT_SID'/IncomingPhoneNumbers.json' -u "$TWILIO_CONNECTED_SUBACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN" -sS | jq` i.e. when you connect, I guess it creates a new subaccount. You use that for authorization only (`-u`) but then you can fetch data for the main account by putting it in the URL! So there's 3 different SIDs: the one for the host app, which is unused, and then 2 for the connected account